# How to install/use a cypress plugin without using npm install

Tags: javascript, plugins, cypress, npm-install, ntlm-authentication

I'm trying to install/use this cypress plugin https://github.com/bjowes/cypress-ntlm-auth for my automation tests so I can login to an application that uses ntlm authenticator, but I cannot use **npm install --save-dev cypress-ntlm-auth** command cause of corporate security policies.
I've downloaded the zip repo release of this plugin and also have cypress installed, but I don't know the exact steps to do this without npm install.

I've tried adding this in the cypress/plugins/index.js file:

```
const ntlmAuth = require('cypress-ntlm-auth-3.2.5/test/e2e/cypress/plugins/index.ts');
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  config = ntlmAuth.initNtlmAuth(config);
  return config;
}
```

and also added this is cypress/support/index.js file:

```
import "cypress-ntlm-auth-master/src/commands"
```

but I have the following error while trying to open cypress: Error: Cannot find module 'cypress-ntlm-auth-3.2.5/test/e2e/cypress/plugins/index.ts' (the index.ts file is in the mentioned location)

I think I might be missing some installing/configuration steps. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you unzipped to `node_modules`, this is the difference between an npm install (left) and a zip (right).

[image]

Try hacking this

- rename the unzipped `src` to `dist`
- add `http-mitm-proxy`

  ```sh
  #!/bin/sh
  basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

  case 'uname' in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
  esac

  if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
    "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../../../http-mitm-proxy/bin/mitm-proxy.js" "$@"
    ret=$?
  else 
    node  "$basedir/../../../http-mitm-proxy/bin/mitm-proxy.js" "$@"
    ret=$?
  fi
  exit $ret
  ```
- add `http-mitm-proxy.cmd`

  ```js
  @IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
    "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\..\..\http-mitm-proxy\bin\mitm-proxy.js" %*
  ) ELSE (
    @SETLOCAL
    @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
    node  "%~dp0\..\..\..\http-mitm-proxy\bin\mitm-proxy.js" %*
  )
  ```

These two files are also found in `/node_modules/.bin` with the file names `cypress-ntlm` and `cypress-ntlm.cmd`, which may be the critical bit, so copy them there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think using yarn might help : `yarn add cypress-ntlm-auth`
Install yarn by : `npm install yarn -g`